# Фото адресата в почте

Tags: email

Отправляю почту со своего домена. Как сделать так, чтобы в почтовых клиентах отображалась нужная мне картинка?

Интересует решение не только для mail.ru, но и другие почтовые службы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/101249

Comment: Я видел этот пост, но так и не понятно что куда дергать

Comment: У каждого почтового сервера дергать что-то свое. Или вообще ни чего, потому что такой фичи нет у кого-то. Читайте документацию у тех почтовых серверов, куда шлете письма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение для mail.ru
https://postmaster.mail.ru/ регистрируем тут домен и добавляем картинку. Так же видим статистику писем от домена для пользователей @mail.ru

Что касается Яндекса, то один из вариантов это подключить ПДД, но до конца не разобрался